# Ruby rails - troubleshoot window.onunload with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to track pageview time via an AJAX call which posts with the `window.onunload` event. Here is my code (the AJAX call I got to work manually with a button pushed by the user, see [Ruby Rails - structuring data for AJAX call to controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888250/ruby-rails-structuring-data-for-ajax-call-to-controller-action), but now I would like this to operate "under the hood" with no action from the user). The load works (I get the alert), but the unload doesn't work (no alert when I close the window -- or should I not even expect that?) Either way, the data isn't being posted to my database. Probably this is another time where my learning JS by necessity is messing me up.

MINOR UPDATE (check that the functions are firing, and then declare the variables outside the onload event to make accessible in the second function):

In the `<body>` of the page view I care about:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var d = new Date();
        alert("load works" + d);
    }

    var d = new Date();
    var starttime = d.getTime();

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        var j = new Date();
        var endtime = j.getTime();
        alert("unload works START:" + d + starttime + "END:" + j + endtime);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/pagetimes/create',
            data: $.param({
                pagetime: {
                    pagename: 'whatever',
                    start: starttime,
                    end: endtime
                }
            })
        });
    }
</script>
```

Just nothing ends up in my database (the POST doesn't go through?)

Comment: declare the starttime variable outside the first function and check. seems like it is not supported in chrome and it is on body tag. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp

Comment: you cannot do that using onunload event, you cannot even using onbeforeunload event. There is no cross browser way of doing what you are trying to do

Comment: can you try `$( window ).unload(function() {` instead of `window.onunload = function()`

Comment: declaring starttime outside of the first function doesn't change anything. @awolff, which part can I not be doing? is there a workaround that would be possible?

Comment: @arun, no fix. am now using the window.onbeforeunload function so that I can at least see the alert go through. the problem now is with the AJAX call, but I don't know enough about this cross-browser issue--will read up if anyone has references to what my issue is here.

Comment: I also moved into the <body>, but still same issue. The functions are being fired properly, but nothing is going thru with AJAX.

Comment: You could try to set your ajax request synch inside beforeunload event with absolutely no guarantee this will work on all browsers

Comment: Yes. Setting option async:false ends up getting the post to the database. Thanks for the pointers on browser compatibility, I will be wary.