# Ajax call to create instance of a model onClick (Rails 4)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'd like to trigger the creation of a model with AJAX when a button is clicked. I defined the `create` action in my controller and added a onClick event listener on the button:

```
 <a class="add-step btn btn-primary">Add</a>
 <script>
   $('.add-step').click(function(){
   console.log("button works");
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/blocks',
        dataType: "son",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { content: "hello" }
      });
   });
 </script>
```

And in my `blocks_controller.rb`:

```
 def create
    @block = Block.new(blocks_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @block.save
        format.json { render json: @block }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @block.errors }
      end
    end
  end

 private 

 def blocks_params
   params.require(:blocks).permit(:content)
 end
```

I do get "button works" in the console, but I also have an error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/blocks 400 (Bad Request)
```

It seems to be an issue with the params (since I don't get a 404, it seems like the `create` action "works") but I can't find what's wrong with it.

Comment: researched for similar issue?

Comment: @Nithin I did, found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888250/ruby-rails-structuring-data-for-ajax-call-to-controller-action but even it's url seems wrong since the POST request has to be made to the /model and not /model/create and it doesn't have a very helpful answer

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/4157037/2231236

Comment: @Nithin just did and added  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" to my AJAX call but I have the same error

Comment: may be you have pass authenticity token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original answer**

```
$.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    url: '/blocks',
    dataType: "script",
    format: "js",
    data: { content: "hello" }
  });
```

**Updated**

Try to do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    url: '/blocks',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { content: "hello" }
  });
```

I think your problem is that the `dataType` should be `json` and that `type` should be `method`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working ... If I do it your way, shouldn't I add a different respond_to in my controller ? Right now it is set to json and not js

Comment: ah sorry i'll update my answer for `json` instead of `js`

Comment: but yes my initial answer would have worked if you used `respond_to` js in your controller